# How to change executable file rights using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a very simple inno script through a wizard in InnoIDE. However the deployed executable file can be run by normal user. How can I enforce that the user has to run it as administrator through the script ?

```
[Setup]
AppId={{03E6645E-2C53-4E90-967B-D0833A8EBDAF}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "                {cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion; Permissions: admins-readexec; 
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,    {#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent;
```

Comment: `How can I enforce that the user has to run it as administrator through the script` -- I thought that's what "PrivilegesRequired=admin" does.

Comment: @Jimmy, that does, but for setup. OP wants that for application for whose the setup is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Inno to change the permissions or manifest of your application.

To make your application ask for admin permissions, you will need to add the appropriate manifest to it. This is different for each different programming language but [many related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+a+program+as+admin&submit=search) have already been asked and answered.

Comment: Wait, I thought the manifest is universal XML *file*, not that it's dependent on programming language. If that's right and you find some tool that can modify this XML *file* (like might be e.g. [`this tool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx)), then you can run that tool from your script before the deployed application is actually packed into the setup (I ♥ preprocessor :-)

Comment: @user1412803, well, seems you take up with the fact it's impossible. Never mind.

Comment: @TLama The manifest is, how you add it differs based on language/compiler though. VB6 requires you add it to the res file before compiling. .NET apps (in VS2005) need a post compile step that calls mt.exe. VS2008+ have a project option to include a manifest (iirc). etc.

Comment: @TLama Oh, and while still technically possible to add during the setup compile /preprocessor phase, how do you test just the executable? what if you build the setup twice? It should be a property of the executable, and nothing to do with the setup. As for your use of the preprocessor, "when you have a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail" :p

Comment: about the preprocessor topic I was kidding (but really, for what I thought would be needed ;-) Thanks for the manifest explanation! And yes, what I forgot on the application testing, but the same you need to do e.g. with the application signing tool ;-) +1

Comment: It is actually possible to deploy the manifest as a separate file next to the executable file.  But that's error prone -- it's much better to compile it into the executable as a resource.  Even better, though, is to ensure that the application doesn't need admin permissions in the first place -- most apps that think they do actually don't.

Answer (score 0):

easier way To make your application ask for admin permissions:

add this value in registry key for your executable file:

```
[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

i prefer usually using above code.

Comment: I can't see in what is this easier than adding manifest. Why in the world would one like to setup their program to run in a compatibility mode *from scratch* ? Avoid doing this. Adding manifest is the right way.

Comment: it is easier because that executable file is not mine (I'm not programmer of that) and i have not intelligent about how it coded and adding manifest file may cause any problem in future and i just repack it for better installation.

Comment: Yeah, and if MS decides to move those registry keys to some other place will surely save your future plans. And it's not easier. Period. If the app. is yours (which is assumed for this question), add a manifest (if your app. really needs it). Many IDEs have a rich support for this. If you're stealing someone's app. for re-pack, use external manifest (if you really need it).